# in indexed database, how to get a keysList in which key start with "some string"?

Tags: html, indexeddb

```
function fetchEmployeeByEmail() {
  try {
    var result = document.getElementById("result");
    result.innerHTML = "";

    if (localDatabase != null && localDatabase.db != null) {
        var range = IDBKeyRange.lowerBound("john");

        var store = localDatabase.db.transaction("employees").objectStore("employees");
        var index = store.index("emailIndex");

        index.get(range).onsuccess = function(evt) {
            var employee = evt.target.result; 
            var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(employee);
            result.innerHTML = jsonStr;   
        };
    }
  }
  catch(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

in above sample, how to get all emails have first name "john"????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nosql approach to databases means you should think about alternate storage access patterns. If you want to support a query by first name, and want to do so in a performant manner, consider storing a derived first name property per employee, create an index on this derived property, and then query the index.

Storing a derived property is redundant from one point of view, sure. It also intuitively feels like a normalization violation. However, the idea here is ultimately that disk space is generally cheap and available but time is not. You can make a trade off in space time to do what you want.  So you have two ways:

1. Don't store a derived property. In your query, loop over all employees. For each employee, access the email property, then do a check, then push the value into an array if it meets your condition, and then do something with the array of matches.
2. Redundantly store a first-name property in your employee store. Create an index on the first-name property.  Then access your store via the index and a condition.

Answer (score 2):

Open an index from the keyword to the keyword with last letter changed with right border:

```
IDBKeyRange.bound(value, increaseLastCharCode(value), false, true);
```

And the function for changing the last character:

```
function increaseLastCharCode(str){
        return str.substring(0, str.length-1) + String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(str.length-1)+1);
}
```

This will open index from "John" to "Joho" and it will not return results starting with "Joho"

Answer (score 1):

change the filter like this:

```
if (localDatabase != null && localDatabase.db != null) { 
    var range = IDBKeyRange.bound("john", "john" + '|', true, true);
codes...
```

Comment: Can you provide some extra explanation?

Comment: @Barranka sure, what you want to know?